# How to implement a macro that defines a new public type and returns an instance of that type?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

I want to implement a struct using `macro_rules!` because the generics require a lot of boilerplate and trait hunting.

The struct in question has a hash table inside but the key and the value types are to be provided by the user. The code is as follows:

```rust
macro_rules! new_ytz {
    ($T: ty) => {
        // define the struct
        pub struct Ytz {
            table: hashbrown::hash_map::HashMap<$T, $T>,
        }

        impl Ytz {
            pub fn new() -> Self {
                Ytz {
                    table: hashbrown::hash_map::HashMap::<$T, $T>::new(),
                }
            }

            pub fn add(&mut self, item: &$T) {
                if self.table.contains_key(item) {
                    *self.table.get_mut(item).unwrap() += *item;
                } else {
                    self.table.insert(*item, *item);
                }
            }

            pub fn largest(&self) -> $T {
                let mut result = 0;
                for v in self.table.values() {
                    if result < *v {
                        result = *v;
                    }
                }
                result
            }
        }
        // construct an instance of the struct and return it
        Ytz::new()
    };
}
```

```rust
// driver
fn main() {
    let mut y = new_ytz!(u64); // should construct the object and return Ytz::new()
    y.add(&71);
    y.add(&25);
    y.add(&25);
    y.add(&25);
    y.add(&34);
    println!("{}", y.largest());
}
```

This won't compile since it tries to paste the struct within the main function:

```
error: expected expression, found keyword `pub`
  --> src/main.rs:4:9
   |
4  |         pub struct Ytz {
   |         ^^^ expected expression
...
40 |     let mut y = new_ytz!(u64); // should construct the object and return Ytz::new()
   |                 ------------- in this macro invocation
```

How can I work around it? How can I paste the struct outside the main function publicly, along with the `impl` block?

Comment: You cannot do this.

Comment: why make life complicated ?

Comment: It's because hunting traits is difficult. For example, to generalize this I'd have to manually find many different kinds traits and a lot of compilation/failure/look for macros/add traits etc. This (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ad12a671c9e8faab349e1859be8f72e) looks ugly but it does the job for now.

Comment: What do you mean by trait hunting? I can tell you without looking at Rust's documentation that `T` needs to implement `Hash`, `Eq`, and `Ord` (and the compiler could tell you the same). The way you wrote it, `T` also needs to implement `Copy`, but it could be modified so `T` needs `Clone` instead.

If you're doing this as a learning exercise, go ahead, but this is like using the processor to implement generics in C++. You can do it, but it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

> generics require a lot of boilerplate

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use core::hash::Hash;
use std::ops::AddAssign;

struct YtzU64<T: Eq + Ord + Hash + Copy + AddAssign> {
    table: HashMap<T, T>
}

impl<T: Eq + Ord + Hash + Copy + AddAssign> YtzU64<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            table: HashMap::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, item: &T) {
        if let Some(item) = self.table.get_mut(item) {
            *item += *item;
        } else {
            self.table.insert(*item, *item);
        }
    }

    pub fn largest(&self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut values = self.table.values();
        let mut largest:Option<T> = values.next().map(|t| *t);
        for v in values {
            if largest < Some(*v) {
                largest = Some(*v);
            }
        }
        largest
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut y = YtzU64::new();
    y.add(&71);
    y.add(&25);
    y.add(&25);
    y.add(&25);
    y.add(&34);
    println!("{}", y.largest().unwrap());
}
```

My translation of your macro requires less boilerplate than your macro. It has two fewer indents, 4 fewer lines (macro_rules!, pattern matching at the top, two close braces at the end). Note that I changed the api slightly, as `largest` now returns an `Option`, to match `std::iter::Iterator::max()`. Also note that your api design is limited to `T:Copy`. You would have to redesign it a little if you want to support `T: ?Copy + Clone` or `T: ?Copy + ?Clone`.

> trait hunting

The compiler is your friend. Watch what happens when I remove one of the trait bounds

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::hash::Hash` is not satisfied
...
```

Using a macro is an interesting exercise, but re-implementing generics using macros is not useful.

Comment: Technically, `PartialOrd` should also work here, if you don't care about the total ordering property.